# A generalization of the concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors with kronecker products

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. We know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ is its associated eigenvector if together they satisfy $Ax = \lambda x$. We can also write this equation as $Ax = \lambda I_n x$, where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. If we want to be even more unnecessary, we can write this equation as

\begin{align}
(A \otimes I_k) (x \otimes I_k) &= (\lambda I_n \otimes I_k) (x \otimes I_k) \\
&= (I_n \otimes \lambda I_k) (x \otimes I_k)
\end{align}

where $``\otimes"$ denotes the [kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Recall that $(A \otimes B) (C \otimes D) = (AB \otimes CD)$ when the products $AB$ and $CD$ make sense.

I am interested in the following generalization: let $B$ be $nk \times nk$. What can we say about matrices $X$ of dimension $nk \times k$ and $\Lambda$ of dimension $k \times k$ that satisfy

\begin{align}
B X = (I_n \otimes \Lambda) X
\end{align}

Evidently, $k = 1$ degenerates to the regular eigenvalue problem. I am not sure if the problem is interesting as is, I am open to suggestions for different setups.